# How to find size of characters of any varchar type variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get number of characters in `varchar` type variable. I have a stored procedure which has variable `@msg varchar(20)` now I want to put check if it's size is more than 14 characters then blah blah else something else but how to find size of it ?

Comment: You can use the `len` function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
IF LEN(@msg)>14
    PRINT 'blah blah'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'something else'
```